# Using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling to create a service and context

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am now updating an integration program written for Dynamics 2015 in order to support Dynamics 365. At the moment it uses the Microsoft.Xrm.Client dll methods to create an organization service context. Is there an equivalent to Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling as Microsoft.Xrm.Client seems unsupported.

```
 var getCRMOrgService = CreateCRMOrgService(logger);
            var client = CreatePosPerfectConnection(logger);

            if (getCRMOrgService != null)
            {
                using (var ctx = new DataContext(new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(getCRMOrgService)))
                {
                    ctx.TryAccessCache(cache => cache.Mode = OrganizationServiceCacheMode.Disabled);
/******Rest of the code******/
```

Here I require to change the CreateCRMOrgService and CrmOrganizationServiceContext Methods to the ones supported by Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll want to switch to `CrmServiceClient`, which is in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector` namespace.

To get the NuGet package:
In your project, right click on the References node and select Manage NuGet Packages. Under Browse search for "xrm tooling". Install Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly and you should be good to go.

Then create a CrmServiceClient via a [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/xrm-tooling/sample-simplified-connection-quick-start)

```
var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Then for the context (query provider) do something like this (please note this is untested code):

```
private List<Entity> getRecords()
{
    using (var context = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext(svc))
    {
        var result = from e in organizationServiceContext.CreateQuery("new_entity")
                     where e.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_field") == "my value"
                     select e;
        return result.Take(100).ToList();
    }
}
```